# number of edges in a transitive closure of a random directed graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

First two definition:

---

**(A) Random Directed Graph:**

Suppose we have a random $DAG(n, p)$. Here is how it's generated:

- Put n distinct nodes on a line, and connect each node in the $i$th order to any node after that; This would form a complete directed graph with $n$ nodes.
- Sample each edge with probability $p$.

The resulting graph will be directed, and acyclic.

---

**(B) Transitive Closure:**

Transitive closure of a graph $\text{closure}(G)$ is the result of connecting all the node pairs $i-j$ (via a direct edge $i \rightarrow j$) such that there is a path connecting $i$ to $j$.

---

**The question is:**

what is the expected number of edges in $\text{closure}(DAG(n, p))$?